# Store the output of foreach loop to array

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using a code to show specific filtered products and i'm trying to integrate this code with an exist function in my theme showing posts in slider . what i'm stuck in is that's i need the output of the foreach loop to be stored in array so i can use it in the function , sorry for my english , here's my code , any help will be highly appreciated

```
//the loop and it output posts with no problems//
<?php
 foreach ( $products as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
<?php endforeach; // end of the loop.   ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

//the slider function and it works through the theme in same logic for example for related products the value is an array  //
<?php 
 $slider_args = array(
        'slides_per_view' => 4 ,
        'img_size' => 'woocommerce_thumbnail',
        'custom_sizes' => false
        );
                
theme_set_loop_prop( 'products_view', 'carousel' );

echo theme_generate_posts_slider( $slider_args, false, //i need to put the array here// $relatedproducts );
?>
```

Comment: you should have a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php

Comment: i checked it but i couldn't to sort it with my code , any example code for how to use it with foreach loop and output the result into array?